# How am I solving for the graphing of a polar equation incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am asked to graph the polar equation: $r = 1 + 2\cos(\theta)$

I create a table, I've read that this table should start at $0$ and increment by $\pi/2$, unless there is some 'n' in the theta of the polar equation, in that case it's $n\theta = \pi/2$ and we increment by that result.

So what I did was set up the table like so:

$\theta........r$

$======$

$0........3$$

$\pi/4......1$

$\pi/2.....-1$

$3\pi/4.....1$

$\pi........3$

$5\pi/4.....1$

$3\pi/2....-1$

I got the $r$ values from evaluating the function with those thetas.
I graph it by first point in the direction of theta and going the distance of $r$ always wrapping around counter clockwise.

My graph looked like this:
[image]

Is there something off with my approach? My table? the increments?

Please help

Thank you

Comment: You are not calculating the values of $r$ correctly.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thank you I keep reviewing it, where are the r values incorrect?

Comment: for example, $1+2\cos\pi=?$

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should get (I used python/matplotlib):

[image: figure]

Answer (score 0):

Your values for $r$ are incorrect.

$$ \begin{align*}
  r(0) &= 1+2(1) = 3 \\
  r(\pi/4) &= 1 + 2(\sqrt{2}/2) = 1 + \sqrt{2} \approx 2.414 \\
  r(\pi/2) &= 1 + 2(0) = 1 \\
  r(3\pi/4) &= 1 + 2(-\sqrt{2}/2) = 1 - \sqrt{2} \approx -0.414 \\
  r(\pi) &= 1 + 2(-1) = -1 \\
  r(5\pi/4) &= 1 + 2(-\sqrt{2}/2) = 1 - \sqrt{2} \approx -0.414 \\
  r(3\pi/2) &= 1 + 2(0) = 1
\end{align*} $$

Now plot these points and you should get something that looks like the plot in Andrei's answer.